# Keep TCP socket-connection alive if no data is currently available

Tags: java, android, serversocket, keep-alive

I have implemented a small HTTP-server which allows clients to connect via HTTP and stream audio-data to them.

My problem is, that in case there's currently no audio-data available, the connection seems to break, either because the client is disconnecting, or due to another reason inside Android.

I'm acting like the following way:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
out.write("Content-Type: audio/wav\r\n");
out.write("Accept-Ranges: none\r\n");
out.write("Connection: keep-alive\r\n"); // additionally added due to answer below
out.write("\r\n");
out.flush();
..
while(len=otherInput.read(audioBuffer)){
 out.write(audioBuffer, 0, len);)
}
```

For sure this is just a snipped of the real code, but it shows what I'm doing.
Now, in case the "otherinput.read()" takes a long time because there's no data available at the moment, I get a

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:499)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:468)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:508)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:270)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushInternal(BufferedOutputStream.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:139)
```

Who can tell me how I can prevent the connection from breaking/closing without a manual heartbeat? Do I miss some header or am I using something the wrong way?

Thanks for your help in advance, tried and searched myself crazy meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems here.

1. Clients of HTTP servers are not well-behaved in the way you seem to expect. Consider a browser. The user can shut it down, go back, navigate away etc, any time he likes, even in the middle of a page load. If you get any error transmitting to the client there's nothing you can do except close the connection and forget about it. Same applies to any server really, but it applies unsolder to HTTP servers.
2. You're not reading the entire request sent by the client. You need to read all the headers until a blank line, then you need to read the body up to the length specified in the Content-length: header, or all the chunks, or until end of stream, as the case may be: see RFC 2616. The effect of this may be that you *cause* the behaviour at (1).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. #1 is for sure totally correct, whereas my clients are DLNA-renderers. They might close the channel by themself in case no data is transmitted for a longer time, but I still think it's a problem on the server's side. About #2, I'm reading the whole input from the client and I'm evaluating the headers etc. This is just something I have not added in the code above. Also in general totally correct. I fear that this might be an issue related to Android, because I'm always stumbling over Android-tickets when searching for such/this problem :/ Thanks again for your hints!